# Inline SVG pattern repeating horizontally and scaling vertically?

Tags: svg

I'm looking for a way to use an inline SVG pattern that scales vertically and only repeats horizontally. Does anyone know if this is possible and if so how?

I know I can makes this just using a SVG as a background-image, but I want to be able to use this SVG in a javascript/component-based workflow so inline is the best fit for that.

Here is link with my work-in-progress: https://codepen.io/devotee/pen/GRJJpKL

And some **code:**

```
<div class="divider">
    <svg width="100%" height="40px">
        <defs>
            <pattern id="pattern" x="0" y="0" width="60" height="6" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <path fill="none" stroke="#F5A861" d="M60 5C45 5 45 1 30 1S15 5 0 5"/>
            </pattern>
        </defs>
    <rect x="10" y="6" width="100%" height="12" fill="url(#pattern)" />
</svg>
```

As you can see in the link, this repeats in both directions, so setting a bigger height value does not accomplish what I want. I would like this pattern to always fill the containers height (or simply be set to a value with CSS) but repeat horizontally.

Here are some images to illustrate what I mean:

**Top is wanted behaviour, bottom is unwanted behaviour:**

[image]

The background scales vertically and does not repeat. It takes as much space vertically as it can (fills parent height or whatever height value it has specified)

**Top is wanted behaviour, bottom is unwanted behaviour:**
[image]
It does not stretch the SVG horizontally but merely repeats it.

Any ideas or input on how to achieve this?

Comment: Please add pictures to clarify your question. Which result exactly would you like to achieve?

Comment: Added images, I hope it's clear now.